# Google Scripts - Using a drop-down menu to show a balance

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have used data validation to create a drop-down menu that will then update some cells to show the budget amount that is remaining from another sheet. Nothing is occurring when I try to update the field.

The first check for if a checkbox is marked true all works, so I know it is entering the first if. I just can't seem to get it to enter the second if.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var sheet=e.range.getSheet();
  var rgA1=e.range.getA1Notation();

  if (sheet.getName()=="Entry") {
   console.log("Entry")

    if (e.value == "TRUE") {
      submit();
      Today();
      e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    }

    if (rgA1=="A8" || rgA1 == "B8") {
      var entry = e.source.getSheetByName("Entry");
      var summary = e.source.getSheetByName("Summary");
      var day = entry.getRange("B9").getValue();
      var month = entry.getRange("B10").getValue();
      var total = entry.getRange("B11").getValue();
      var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yy");
      //var daysRemaining = DATEIF(today, summary.getRange("D4"), "D");cell functions not allow
      //var monthsRemaining = DATEIF(today, summary.getRange("D4"), "M");cell functions not allowed

      console.log("Entered 2nd if")

      if (e.value == summary.getRange("B59").getValue) {
        var balance = summary.getRange("E59").getValue
         console.log("Entered 3rd if")
      }

      else if (e.value == summary.getRange("B60").getValue()) {
        var balance = summary.getRange("E60").getValue()
      }

      else if (e.value == summary.getRange("B61").getValue()) {
        var balance = summary.getRange("E61").getValue()
      }

      else if (e.value == summary.getRange("B62").getValue()) {
        var balance = summary.getRange("E62").getValue()
      }

      else if (e.value == summary.getRange("B63").getValue()) {
        var balance = summary.getRange("E63").getValue()
      }

      else if (e.value == summary.getRange("B64").getValue()) {
        var balance = summary.getRange("E64").getValue()
      }

      else if (e.value == summary.getRange("B65").getValue()) {
        var balance = summary.getRange("E65").getValue()
      }

      else if (e.value == summary.getRange("B66").getValue()) {
        var balance = summary.getRange("E66").getValue()
      }

      else if (e.value == summary.getRange("B67").getValue()) {
        var balance = summary.getRange("E67").getValue()
      }

      else if (e.value == summary.getRange("B68").getValue()) {
        var balance = summary.getRange("E68").getValue()
      }

      else if (e.value == summary.getRange("B69").getValue()) {
        var balance = summary.getRange("E69").getValue()
      }

      else if (e.value == summary.getRange("B70").getValue()) {
        var balance = summary.getRange("E70").getValue()
      }

      else if (e.value == summary.getRange("B71").getValue()) {
        var balance = summary.getRange("E71").getValue()
      }

      day.setValue(balance / 56);
      month.setValue(balance / 2);
      total.setValue(balance);

    }
  }
}
```

Any thanks would be hugely appreciated!

*EDIT* 5/8/20

Fixed using Cooper's suggestions

Also [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UNulfsC9QdiRpQVgO2dksc0VA3OzEdwh0ne9-N8AFYw/edit?usp=sharing) is a copy of the sheet this script is for.

Comment: Let’s check step by step. I recommend use "reverse if condition" like `if (sheet != "Entry") return; ...//continue `

Comment: @hoangdv I used that and it thinks the sheet is != "Entry".  I had that same thing working earlier today though, so I have no idea why it thinks it isn't Entry

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your code.  I made some note in your question and made a few corrections in my answer.  Please go ahead and make the changes and resubmit the corrected code and I'll help you from there.

Comment: Can you please share a sanitized copy of the spreadsheet you are working on?

Comment: @Cooper resubmitted code and added a link to copy of sheet. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

That's better but you still have some problems at the end.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet=e.range.getSheet();
  var rgA1=e.range.getA1Notation();
  if (sheet.getName()=="Entry") {
   console.log("Entry")
    if (e.value == "TRUE") {
      submit();
      Today();
      e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    }

    if (rgA1=="A8" || rgA1 == "B8") {
      var entry = e.source.getSheetByName("Entry");
      var summary = e.source.getSheetByName("Summary");
      var dA=entry.getRange('B9:B11').getValues();
      var day = dA[0][0];
      var month = dA[0][1];
      var total = dA[0][2];
      var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yy");
      var bvs=summary.getRange('B59:B71').getValues();
      var erg=summary.getRange('E59:E71');
      var evs=erg.getValues();
      for(var i=0;i<bvs.length;i++) {
        if(e.value==bvs[i][0]) {
          var balance=evs[i][0];
          break;
        }
      }
      entry.getRange('B9').setValue(balance/56);
      entry.getRange('B10').setValue(balance/2);
      entry.getRange('B11').setValue(balance);
      //day.setValue(balance / 56);//day is not a range so there is no  setValue Method 
      //month.setValue(balance / 2);//day is not a range so there is no  setValue Method 
      //total.setValue(balance);//day is not a range so there is no  setValue Method 

    }
  }
}
```